# Group by and additional columns for each language/translation of product name

Tags: mysql

If I have these data in MySQL database:

```
PID     LANG    TRANS
1       EN      Apple
1       DE      Apfle
```

I want to get results in sql:

```
PID     EN_TRANSLATION      DE_TRANSLATION
1       Apple               Apfle
```

How to do this? I already have tables and everything but need help writing query that will give me columns per language per result for each product.

**NOTE: I don't know set of language(s) ! It can be EN, DE or whatever else..**

Thx!

Comment: How many `LANG` are possible ? In the example you have only 2.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know set of languages.. it can be EN, DE or whatever else... it is free to user add any language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have known set of `LANG` then you can use the following technique to generate the pivot view

```
select 
PID,
max(case when LANG = 'EN' then TRANS end) as EN_TRANSLATION,
max(case when LANG = 'DE' then TRANS end) as DE_TRANSLATION
from table_bame
group by PID
```

If the `LANG` values are unknown then you need to use dynamic sql for this as

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when LANG = ''',
      LANG,
      ''' then TRANS end) AS ',
     concat(LANG,'_TRANSLATION')
    )
  ) into @sql
from table_name ;

set @sql = concat('select PID, ', @sql, ' from table_name 
                  group by PID
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95d29/1

Comment: unfortunately i don't know set of languages.. it can be EN, DE or whatever else... it is free to user add any language

Comment: In that case you will need dynamic sql, check the update.